# c# - split string inside textbox by colon and get the first string and second string

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

I have a text box that when I type into it such as "alfa:rady," I need the first string (alfa) and second string (rady) put into different text boxes.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // what should i write?
    }
```

This illustrates what I mean:

[image: this one]

Comment: UserName.Text = textBox1.Split(':')[0];Password.Text = textBox1.Split(':')[1];

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but to split strings using a colon you can use the following `string[] data = text.Split(':');`. And then `data[0]` contains the first string and `data[1]` contains the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the 2 values using `string.Split(char)`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] arr = textBox1.Text.Split(':');
    string username = arr[0];
    string password = arr[1];

    // Now you can use the 2 variables in other textboxes
    textUsername.Text = username;
    textPassword.Text = password;
}
```